# SQL How can I optimize splitting a string and inserting the words into a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway to do this in less time? I am taking the summary column from my case table and splitting the data word by word into my words table using the following loop:

```
Example case table
CaseID | CaseNumber | Summary
1        111111       This is a summary
2        111112       This is Summary 2 

DECLARE 
@n int = 1
;
WHILE @n <= 1000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO words (caseID, caseNumber, pn, word)
SELECT caseID, caseNumber, pn, word FROM dbo.Split6(' ', (select summary 
from 
cases where caseID = @n)) where caseID = @n group by caseID,caseNumber, pn, 
word
option (maxrecursion 0)
SET @n = @n+1;
END
GO
```

It works, but it is slow. Took 3 hours to break down 1000 cases. I have 100,000 cases. Is there a way I can do this more efficiently? Here is the split function I'm using:

```
Split6 function:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split6] (
@sep CHAR(1) 
,@s nVARCHAR(4000) 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
WITH Pieces(caseID,caseNumber, pn, start, stop) AS (
            SELECT cs.caseID
            ,cs.caseNumber
                ,1
                ,1
                ,CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
            FROM cases cs

            UNION ALL

            SELECT caseID
                ,caseNumber
                ,pn + 1
                ,stop + 1
                ,CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
            FROM Pieces
            WHERE stop > 0
            )
    SELECT caseID
        ,caseNumber
        ,pn
        ,SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE 
                WHEN stop > 0
                    THEN stop - start
                ELSE 512
                END) AS word
    FROM Pieces
    )  GO
```

Comment: you'd do better with a programming language rather than sql for this..or if your version of sql server supports [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql), use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid loops whenever possible.

The following uses a Parse/Split function in concert with a Cross Apply (use Outer Apply to show null values).

As far as performance goes... useing a test sample of 100,000 records with a average of 5 words each, the execution time is 2.2 seconds.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([CaseID] varchar(50),[CaseNumber] varchar(50),[Summary] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (1,111111,'This is a summary')
,(2,111112,'This is Summary 2')

Select A.CaseID
      ,A.CaseNumber
      ,B.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Summary,' ') B
```

**Returns**

```
CaseID  CaseNumber  RetSeq  RetVal
1       111111      1       This
1       111111      2       is
1       111111      3       a
1       111111      4       summary
2       111112      1       This
2       111112      2       is
2       111112      3       Summary
2       111112      4       2
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

> **EDIT - Another Parse/Split Function**

The following TVF is slightly faster then the XML version, but limited to 8K.  For example, on 5,000 sample records, with an average of 36 "words", it was 20ms faster than the XML version.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Comment: @Bendgame Happy it helped